# Run unit test error: xxx.h not found while this app can run and build success

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, unit-testing, xcode10.1

1. OC + swift project
2. Multi target project for diff used
3. OC and swift test case can't run success, it is show xxx.h file not found after running the tese case, and the xxx.h not only same it is diff .h file at diff run
4. This project build or run at simulator and real device it is ok
5. Have try to add third part framework at framework search, header search
6. Have try to add dependence target
7. Have clean project, restart project then re-run test case, fail too

Comment: are you writing a bug-report, aren't you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. this maybe is the config missing
2. the easy way to fix this is delete origin test target, please save the origin test case before delete
3. create new unit test target, merge the origin test case into new target